# Logon batch script - Nested variables in a FOR statement not resolving properly

Tags: batch-file

I am updating a windows logon batch script. I wanted to simplify the volume of lines needed to map all the necessary drives, but be able to make defining the script for the user group easy. Presently I have all the drive paths defined as variables, as well as the user groups and what drive letters they get.

The problem is that I have need of a nested variable in a FOR statement. The nested variable needs to complete the name of the variable it is nested in. For example:

I have user/group variables:
`set john=i,j,l,m,o,p,q,r,s,u,y,z` (6 users/groups like this are defined)

drive mapping variables: `set mapdrv_i=i: \\sqlserver\ARCHIVE>NUL` (necessary drives in the group i-z are defined)

My FOR statement is `for %%C in (%john%) do if defined mapdrv_%%C net use %%mapdrv_%%C%%>NUL && if Errorlevel 0 ( ECHO. %%mapdrv_%%C%% - Mapped. ) else ( ECHO. Error mapping: %%mapdrv_%%C%% )`

I do have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` set early on in the script.

This is intended to allow me to define what drives are mapped simply by changing the user/group defined in the `in ( )` portion of the FOR statement. The problem is that `%%mapdrv_%%C%%` resolves `%%C` properly but does not resolve further, it litterally places `%mapdrv_N%` into the command so all `net use` commands produced by the FOR statement obviously fail.

How do I correct the nested `%%mapdrv_%%C%%` to allow variable to be properly resolved and the command to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using delayedexpansion, change %%mapdrv_%%C%% to !mapdrv_%%C! and it should work.

Comment: Thank you - made the change and while I had to contend with finding a typo that was also causing me a headache, this worked perfectly.